# Downloading CSV file from web generates strange output

Tags: r, csv

I am trying to download a CSV file from https://www.cato.org/human-freedom-index/2023. The link to the file is https://www.cato.org/sites/cato.org/files/human-freedom-index-files/2023-Human-Freedom-Index-Data.csv. When I use `read.csv` to load the file it generates the following output

```
> dd <- read.csv('https://www.cato.org/sites/cato.org/files/human-freedom-index-files/2023-Human-Freedom-Index-Data.csv')
> dd[1,1]
[1] "<head>"
> dd[2,1]
[1] "<META NAME=robots CONTENT=noindex,nofollow>"
> dd[3,1]
[1] "<script src=/_Incapsula_Resource?SWJIYLWA=5074a744e2e3d891814e9a2dace20bd4,719d34d31c8e3a6e6fffd425f7e032f3>"
> dd[4,1]
[1] "</script>"
> dd[5,1]
[1] "<body>"
> dd[6,1]
[1] "</body></html>"
```

But when I click on the link on the website, it downloads the actual CSV file as expected. Any ideas what might be going on here?

Comment: You may have better luck using `download.file` to download the file and then read it in from your computer.

Comment: @GregorThomas I tried using `download.file` and it has exactly the same behavior as read.csv.

Comment: Your code works fine on my machine. dd[1,1] will get [1] 2021. You may want to update your packages and try again

Comment: I also get no trouble running your code

Comment: Having same issue as OP, maybe it's location-specific.

Answer (score 1):

Works for me..

```r
dd <- read.csv("https://www.cato.org/sites/cato.org/files/human-freedom-index-files/2023-Human-Freedom-Index-Data.csv")
dd[1:6, 1:5]
#>   year iso countries                        region hf_score
#> 1 2021 ALB   Albania                Eastern Europe     7.67
#> 2 2021 DZA   Algeria    Middle East & North Africa     4.82
#> 3 2021 AGO    Angola            Sub-Saharan Africa     5.76
#> 4 2021 ARG Argentina Latin America & the Caribbean     6.85
#> 5 2021 ARM   Armenia       Caucasus & Central Asia     7.99
#> 6 2021 AUS Australia                       Oceania     8.52
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

With `download.file()`

```r
f <- tempfile()

download.file("https://www.cato.org/sites/cato.org/files/human-freedom-index-files/2023-Human-Freedom-Index-Data.csv",
              destfile = f)
dd <- read.csv(f)
dd[1:6, 1:5]
#>   year iso countries                        region hf_score
#> 1 2021 ALB   Albania                Eastern Europe     7.67
#> 2 2021 DZA   Algeria    Middle East & North Africa     4.82
#> 3 2021 AGO    Angola            Sub-Saharan Africa     5.76
#> 4 2021 ARG Argentina Latin America & the Caribbean     6.85
#> 5 2021 ARM   Armenia       Caucasus & Central Asia     7.99
#> 6 2021 AUS Australia                       Oceania     8.52
```

<sup>Created on 2024-01-19 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>

Edit: there might be insight: https://community.fabric.microsoft.com/t5/Power-Query/Get-Post-Method-returns-lt-META-NAME-quot-robots-quot-CONTENT/td-p/1556536

I would try to access it from different network.

Comment: I tried this from a different IP address and get the same (negative) result. But I think the link to the Microsoft discussion group is what's going on. There must be a firewall which recognizes this as non-human access. Is there a solution for that -- in the sense that this file is freely available to download directly, but it would just make for an easier workflow to have the download automated.

Comment: What happens if you delete all cookies in browser and try to open the csv there? The other option might be to use rselenium +selenium serwer.

Comment: File opens in browser with no problem. It's the API download from R that gets into the firewall issue.